# Shortcut to adding req values to a response for rendering in Express View

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using Node/Express (most recent production versions)

I have a form where I collect new account info. The user can add a username, etc.

In the view handler, I check a mongodb database to see if the username is unique. If it is not, I generate a message and reload the original view. Since the original request was a post, all of the data the user posted is in req.body. I would like to add the data the user submitted on the response. I could do it by specifically adding each value to the response. But isn't there an easier way to add all the request data back to the response? And is there a way to render that in the view (i'm using ejs) I tried res.send(JSON) coupled with ejs variables. Doing so generates errors saying the variables aren't available.

---

Here's my function (ignore the users.createUser(req) - it's not finished yet):

```
createAccount: function(req, res, next){
    users.createUser(req);
    res.render('create_account', {
        layout: 'secure_layout',
        title: 'Create Account',
        givenName: req.body.givenName,
        username: req.body.username,
        familyName: req.body.familyName
    });
},
```

And here's my view:

```
<form action="/createAccount" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="givenName" value="<%= givenName %>"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="familyName" value="<%= familyName %>"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<%= username %>"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

It seems overly complex to have to add each of the values. I tried {body: req.body} but values were never added to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're after, but if you want to render an ejs view with data that was on the request body, you would do something along these lines:

```
app.post('/foo', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('view', {body: req.body});
});
```

view.ejs:

```
<ul>
<% for(var key in body) { %>
  <li><%= key %>: <%= body[key] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I added additional info.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for but has given me a good idea how to do what I want. I'm just looking for a way to add the data already attached the request body to the response and then extract it from the response. I think <%= body[key] %> should do the trick.